# Webpack vs Vite for PHP (Yii2) SSR. Is there a built-in dead code eliminating feature in Vite?

Tags: php, webpack, optimization, yii, vite

I need to eliminate dead code and render blocking things in a PHP project. The issue of optimization is very acute. I need to either configure webpack and manually add TreeShaking and some things that can help remove dead css code or add Vite. I heard that you don't need to manually do it in Vite, it's built-in and the process is less painful with Vite. Can somebody help me with what to choose. There are not many articles and info on Vite.

Comment: It sounds like your real question is "Do/can either Webpack or Vite eliminate dead code?"

Comment: @LLSv2.0, no I know I can, I'm not sure if I can use vite with it's built in dead code elimination feature, I'm leaning towards vite but I'm not sure as there isn't much info